# Omines Datatables - Depth > 2, multiple relation support with orderable/search functionalities

Tags: php, datatables, symfony4

I tried to get this working:

```
$table = $this->createDataTable()
                ->add('firstname', TextColumn::class, ['label' => 'Vorname', 'orderable'=> true, 'field' => 'personalData.firstname'])
                ->add('lastname', TextColumn::class, ['label' => 'Nachname', 'orderable'=> true, 'field' => 'personalData.lastname'])
                ->add('email', TextColumn::class, ['label' => 'Nachname', 'orderable'=> true, 'field' => 'personalData.lastname'])
                ->add('phone', TextColumn::class, ['label' => 'Telefon', 'orderable'=> true, 'field' => 'personalData.phone'])
                ->add('mobilePhone', TextColumn::class, ['label' => 'Mobil', 'orderable'=> true, 'field' => 'personalData.mobilePhone'])
                ->add('gender', TextColumn::class, ['label' => 'Gender', 'orderable'=> true, 'field' => 'personalData.gender.abbreviation'])
                ->add('lastModified', DateTimeColumn::class, ['label' => 'letzte Änderung', 'orderable'=> true, 'format' => 'd.m.Y H:i:s'])
                ->add('dateCreated', DateTimeColumn::class, ['label' => 'Datum Erstellung', 'orderable'=> true, 'format' => 'd.m.Y H:i:s'])
                ->add('actions', TextColumn::class, ['label' => 'Aktionen', 'orderable'=> false, 'render' => function($value, $context) {
                        $user_id = $context->getId();
                        return sprintf('<button type="button" data-user-id="%s" class="btn btn-primary edit-user-btn"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt fa-fw fa-fw"></i></button><button type="button" data-user-id="%s" class="btn btn-danger del-user-btn margin-left-10"><i class="fas fa-trash fa-fw fa-fw"></i></button>', $user_id, $user_id);
                    }])
                ->createAdapter(ORMAdapter::class, [
            'entity' => User::class,
        ]);
```

This results in the following error:
Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class App\Entity\Gender could not be converted to string

So as workaround I could add the __toString method to the entity but unfortunately it does not solve the problem so that this column is also orderable.

Then I tried this approach:

```
$table = $this->createDataTable()
                ->add('firstname', TextColumn::class, ['label' => 'Vorname', 'orderable'=> true, 'field' => 'personalData.firstname'])
                ->add('lastname', TextColumn::class, ['label' => 'Nachname', 'orderable'=> true, 'field' => 'personalData.lastname'])
                ->add('email', TextColumn::class, ['label' => 'Nachname', 'orderable'=> true, 'field' => 'personalData.lastname'])
                ->add('phone', TextColumn::class, ['label' => 'Telefon', 'orderable'=> true, 'field' => 'personalData.phone'])
                ->add('mobilePhone', TextColumn::class, ['label' => 'Mobil', 'orderable'=> true, 'field' => 'personalData.mobilePhone'])
                ->add('gender', TextColumn::class, ['label' => 'Geschlecht', 'orderable'=> true, 'render' => function($value ,$context) {
                        $user_id = $context->getId();

                        $user = $this->getDoctrine()
                                ->getRepository(User::class)
                                ->findOneBy(['id' => $user_id]);

                        return $user->getPersonalData()->getGender()->getAbbreviation();
                    }])
                ->add('lastModified', DateTimeColumn::class, ['label' => 'letzte Änderung', 'orderable'=> true, 'format' => 'd.m.Y H:i:s'])
                ->add('dateCreated', DateTimeColumn::class, ['label' => 'Datum Erstellung', 'orderable'=> true, 'format' => 'd.m.Y H:i:s'])
                ->add('actions', TextColumn::class, ['label' => 'Aktionen', 'orderable'=> false, 'render' => function($value, $context) {
                        $user_id = $context->getId();
                        return sprintf('<button type="button" data-user-id="%s" class="btn btn-primary edit-user-btn"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt fa-fw fa-fw"></i></button><button type="button" data-user-id="%s" class="btn btn-danger del-user-btn margin-left-10"><i class="fas fa-trash fa-fw fa-fw"></i></button>', $user_id, $user_id);
                    }])
                ->createAdapter(ORMAdapter::class, [
            'entity' => User::class,
        ]);
```

Now I can see the table loading but if I try to order the table I'm getting the following error message:

```
Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException:
[Syntax Error] line 0, col -1: Error: Expected Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER, got end of string.

  at vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php:54
  at Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException::syntaxError('line 0, col -1: Error: Expected Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER, got end of string.', object(QueryException))
     (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php:457)
  at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->syntaxError('Doctrine\\ORM\\Query\\Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER')
     (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php:325)
  at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->match(102)
     (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php:1022)
  at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->ResultVariable()
     (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php:1521)
  at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->OrderByItem()
     (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php:1408)
  at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->OrderByClause()
     (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php:884)
  at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->SelectStatement()
     (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php:848)
  at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->QueryLanguage()
     (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php:261)
  at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->getAST()
     (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/Parser.php:360)
  at Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser->parse()
     (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query.php:286)
  at Doctrine\ORM\Query->_parse()
     (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query.php:234)
  at Doctrine\ORM\Query->getResultSetMapping()
     (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php:902)
  at Doctrine\ORM\AbstractQuery->iterate(array(), 1)
     (vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query.php:689)
  at Doctrine\ORM\Query->iterate(array(), 1)
     (vendor/omines/datatables-bundle/src/Adapter/Doctrine/ORMAdapter.php:205)
  at Omines\DataTablesBundle\Adapter\Doctrine\ORMAdapter->getResults(object(Query))
     (vendor/omines/datatables-bundle/src/Adapter/AbstractAdapter.php:51)
  at Omines\DataTablesBundle\Adapter\AbstractAdapter->getData(object(DataTableState))
     (vendor/omines/datatables-bundle/src/DataTable.php:372)
  at Omines\DataTablesBundle\DataTable->getResultSet()
     (vendor/omines/datatables-bundle/src/DataTable.php:331)
  at Omines\DataTablesBundle\DataTable->getResponse()
     (src/Controller/UsersController.php:100)
  at App\Controller\UsersController->getUsers(object(Request))
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:151)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:68)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:198)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
     (public/index.php:24)
```

So I have an Entity "User" and this has a relation to the entity "personalData" - in addition "personalData" has a relation to "gender"
--> I want to have the gender data displayed in the datatables and keep the order and search functionalities working

Is there any workaround or is this a bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found the solution with a custom query adapter:

```
$table->createAdapter(ORMAdapter::class, [
            'entity' => User::class,
            'query' => function (QueryBuilder $builder) {
                $builder
                        ->select('user')
                        ->from(User::class, 'user')
                        ->leftJoin('user.personalData', 'personalData')
                        ->leftJoin('personalData.gender', 'gender')
                ;
            },
        ]);
```

With this adapter I could get the gender columns with this:

```
->add('gender', TextColumn::class, ['label' => 'Gender', 'orderable'=> true, 'field' => 'gender.abbreviation'])
```

Perhaps it is simply not possible with the default behaviour of omines datatables?

Comment: Your solution is entirely correct. Your use case cannot be unambiguously solved by 'magic', so you have to be explicit about your intents. And this is the right way to do that   :)